# Basic side to side movement in Corona/Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've been trying for hours to get my character to move side to side. The basic aim of the game is to have the character jump up crates. I have the sprite code to make him move all around the screen but I can't make it so he only moves on the X.

```
local touchX, touchY

local touchScreen = function(e)
    --print(e.phase, e.x, e.y)
    if e.phase == "began" then
        touchX = e.x
        touchY = e.y
    elseif e.phase == "moved" then
        --spriteAsh.x = spriteAsh.x + (e.x - touchX)
        --spriteAsh.y = spriteAsh.y + (e.y - touchY)
        local difX = e.x - touchX
        local difY = e.y - touchY

        spriteAsh:applyForce(difX *50, difY * 50, spriteAsh.x, spriteAsh.y)

        touchX = e.x
        touchY = e.y
    elseif e.phase == "ended" then

    end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)

local updateGame = function(e)

    local seq
    local velX, velY = spriteAsh:getLinearVelocity()
    print (velX, velY)

    if math.abs (velX) >= math.abs (velY) then
            --horizonal
        if velX > 0 then
        seq  ="right_run"
                    else
            seq = "left_run"
                end

        else
        if velY > 0 then
        seq = "down_run"
        else
         seq = "up_run"

        end

    end

    if spriteAsh.sequence ~= seq then
    spriteAsh:setSequence(seq)
    spriteAsh:play()
    end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", updateGame)
```

Comment: Please consider indenting your code in 'updateGame' more consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying a force in both x and y, so my first guess is that motion will occur along both axes. Don't apply a force in the y direction:

```
spriteAsh:applyForce(difX *50, 0, spriteAsh.x, spriteAsh.y)
```

Note that the place you apply a force makes a difference, just as it would in reality: if you push on a stick at its center, the whole stick moves, but if you push at one end (perpendicular to it) it will rotate, very differet.

Note also that you are applying a force. Force changes current motion. If there already is motion along y due to some other factor, putting 0 force will not cancel out the y motion. If you really want to constrain y motion it may be worthwhile setting the velocity to 0 at every frame (in update()).

Comment: Ok great then please accept it so others know it has been answered and solved the problem.